# Get the redirect URL with cURL

Tags: centos, curl, html

I am trying to get the source HTML code from the latest posts but...

This URL:

```
http://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?do=getnew
```

Redirect me to:

```
http://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?searchid=26505884
```

Where I can find the latest posts

How can I get the final URL with cURL?

If I use:

```
curl -s http://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?do=getnew > $shDir$urlLatestPosts
```

Then it will get other page than what I am looking for, so is there anyway to get that final URL?

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl -L`.  From the manual:

```
   -L, --location
          (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option
          will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown.  When  authentica-
          tion  is  used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it won't be able to intercept the user+password. See
          also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

          When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if the HTTP  response  was  301,
          302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodified method.
```

Comment: I tried it before asking, not work..

Comment: Could you be more specific than 'not work'?